# Android studio 1.2 beta 'cannot resolve symbol' error

Tags: android

Like in the title, I have many of this errors, but the most strange thing is that I can run the app and that it runs without problem.

I post the gradle files and a fragment of the code of the my app, hoping that they can be helpfull to find the solution at this realy annoying problem.

This is the first build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 

all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is the second build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unisa.unistore"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseFacebookUtils-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

This is the code:

```
import android.content.Context; //Cannot resolve symbol 'Context'
import android.content.Intent; //Cannot resolve symbol 'Intent'
import android.os.Bundle; //Cannot resolve symbol 'Bundle'
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; //Cannot resolve symbol 'FragmentActivity'

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics; //Cannot resolve symbol 'ParseAnalytics'
import com.unisa.unistore.R;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity { //Cannot resolve symbol 'FragmentActivity'
    private MainFragment mainFragment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

But in your `Gradle` I don't see line in `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
```

Just add this line and press `sync now` in top right corner of `Studio`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yurets, thank you for your ansewer... unfortunately I add that line in the gradle, but android studio continues to signal the same errors :(

Comment: @Danix89, beta always contains a lot of bugs... I've just checked just "known" bugs in 1.2 AS and there is a full ocean of them... but if you say it compiles and runs successfully maybe it is just internal error and it will be fixed in the very next subversion.

Comment: really probable also because there are many bugs even in the stable versions :/
Then - as soon as possible - I try to import the project in the latest stable version of android studio and i will let you know.

Comment: with the latest stable version there aren't those errors, so it's a bug of Android Studio... thanks Yurets :D